# Kindle online formating Framework or Tool can be used for web application?

Tags: web-services, frameworks, formatting, epub, kindle

This is my first time to post a question in here at stackoverflow:

I'm currently research on Kindle online formating,I have seem couple websites that currently support online kindle format, e.g.

http://www.epubconverter.com/epub-to-mobi-converter/

I know there is desktop application like "Calibre" and "Kindlegen"
But, not sure how to implement it through a web service。
I was wondering if anyone knows there exists some framework or tools that can be implemented like that,I will be really appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're on Rails, you can use the [kindlegen gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/kindlegen) for installing `kindlegen`, then use that to convert to MOBI files (which is what we ended up doing). We also looked into installing the command-line `calibre` tools, but couldn't get it working on CentOS 5.8.

Comment: So you are pretty much by using Rails and call Kindlegen as a local application to convert html to Kindle Format ? I thought about to doing something like that. But not sure if this is the best way to do it for web-service

Comment: Awesome, I will try that out.

Comment: Another thing I was wondering is, have you try to convert html to article(Like the "Send to kindle" function). It will automatically convert a web page to article like mobi

Comment: Yeah, we've done that (on a very limited basis) as well, and it still works -- the problem is making sure all the styles are working in kindlegen, and that's more difficult.